# How to create a circle around the user's location (blue dot) on Google Maps? I am creating a Geofence app

Tags: android, android-geofence

I am creating a Geofence app where I want it to only create a geofence or circle on the user's current location. So far the solution is to create a marker on the map, but I don't intend on using map markers. Wherever the blue dot is located on the map, I want it to generate a geofence circle around it. What can I do?

```
private void startGeofence() {
    Log.i(TAG, "startGeofence");
    Geofence geofence = createGeofence( geoFenceMarker.getPosition(), GEOFENCE_RADIUS);
    GeofencingRequest geofencingRequest = createGeofenceRequest(geofence);
    addGeofence(geofencingRequest);
}

private Marker geoFenceMarker;
private Circle geofenceLimit;
private void drawGeofence() {
    if (geofenceLimit != null){
        geofenceLimit.remove();
    }

    CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
            .center( geoFenceMarker.getPosition())
            .strokeColor(Color.argb(50, 70,70,70))
            .fillColor( Color.argb(100, 150,150,150) )
            .radius( GEOFENCE_RADIUS );
    geofenceLimit = googleMap.addCircle( circleOptions );

}
```

Comment: These are few websites with documentation, hope it helps. Nevertheless, I have a similar task so in about 2-3 days if this question isn't answered I will do so.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-coordinates

Comment: But this is javascript?

Comment: My mistake, sorry XX

Answer (score 1):

You can use Circle class to draw the circle in users current location.

```
Circle drawCircle = map.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
 .center(new LatLng(loc.latitude, loc.longitude))
 .radius(1000)
 .strokeColor(Color.RED)
 .fillColor(Color.BLUE));
```

You can get more info from: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle

Hope this helps to you.